# Sumologic - split JSON array into multiple records

Tags: arrays, sumologic

I am passing a JSON array object in the HTTP `POST` as

```
[{"level":"INFO","data": "Test 1"},{"level":"INFO","data": "Test 2"}]
```

This message is seen as 1 object/log message in SumoLogic. How can I tell SumoLogic to consider each JSON object as an independent object and show 2 log messages instead of one?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this can't be done with the json operator. But, have a look at [the docs for the "parse regex" operator](https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Search_Query_Language/01_Parse_Operators/02_Parse_Variable_Patterns_Using_Regex). There's an option called "multi" which creates a new message for each match of the regex. In your case, something like this might do the trick:

```
parse regex "\{?<fieldname>.*?\}" multi
```

I didn't try this in the product itself, but here is [Regex101 link to play with the regex](https://regex101.com/r/WNyJOK/1).

Comment: Here's an example I used to parse some JSON
`| parse regex field=event "\"fieldName\":\s*\"(?<fieldName>.*?)\"" multi`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual answer to this is to not send your logs as an array. Instead include each json object in your body with a '\n' at the end for Sumo to consider these as individual log messages.

```
{"level":"INFO","data": "Test 1"}\n
{"level":"INFO","data": "Test 2"}\n
```